# Regex para separar por mayúsculas

Tags: python, regex

Estoy intentando hacer un regex que me separe un string, partiéndolo por letras mayúsculas que vayan precedidas de una letra minúscula (o el inicio).

Por ejemplo `Master en Regulatory AffairsConocimientos de ToxicologíaSector-producto-mercadoNormativa legal vigentePrevención en riesgos laboralesAPPC`, debería obtener como coincidencias `[Master en Regulatory Affairs, Conocimientos de Toxicología, Sector-producto-mercado, Normativa legal vigente, Prevención en riesgos laborales, APPC]`.

He probado con `[A-Z][^A-Z]*` y `[a-z]([A-Z][^A-Z]*)` y algunas otras, pero no me han funcionado.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Puedes usar

```
.+?[a-z](?=[A-Z]|$)|[A-Z]+$
```

Básicamente se divide en dos partes

- La primera parte es `.+?[a-z](?=[A-Z]|$)` y considera todas las palabras que terminen en minúscula y luego siga una mayúscula pero que no considere el grupo (un [positive lookahead](https://www.regextutorial.org/positive-and-negative-lookahead-assertions.php)).
- La segunda `[A-Z]+$` considera el caso en el que las mayúsculas están al final del texto.

Demo:

```js
const str = 'Master en Regulatory AffairsConocimientos de ToxicologíaSector-producto-mercadoNormativa legal vigentePrevención en riesgos laboralesAPPC'

const re = /.+?[a-z](?=[A-Z]|$)|[A-Z]+$/g

const matches = str.match(re)

console.log(matches)
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias!

Comment: Actualice mi pregunta porque faltaba el caso donde tuvieras el string `"FooBar"` y los matches fueran `["Foo", "Bar"]`